# iphone: facebook/linked in type side menu

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Can somebody help me out how can I achieve a Facebook/linked in type side menu. I have achieved a slider view which slides and display menu, now i am not able to figure out how to display screens corresponding to each menu.

I have thought to have multiple navigation controllers corresponding to each menu option and load the navigationcontrollers top viewcontroller on each menu item click.

I dont want to use a 3rd party library for this

Looking forward for the answer.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution at [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController).

Comment: I dont want to use a 3rd party library for this